# Como passar um Objeto para outra página usando AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Gostaria de saber sobre a manipulação de objetos entre páginas utilizando AngularJS, por exemplo:
tenho uma página produto, nela faço uma requisição e trago meus dados usando o básico de AngularJS.

Meu problema está quando preciso passar um objeto selecionado para outra página, quais os métodos para se fazer isto utilizando AngularJS?

Answer (score 3):

Trabalhando com HTML5 existe o recurso implementado [**window.sessionStorage**](https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/) que tem como finalidade guarda informações enquanto a sessão do navegador existir, ou seja, até você fechar o navegador. Nesse exemplo tem o JQuery e o Angular para ser referenciado nas páginas.

*Exemplo de Código*

***home.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var App = angular.module('App', []);
            App.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http){
               $scope.peoples = [
                 {id: 1, name: 'People 1'},  
                 {id: 2, name: 'People 2'},
                 {id: 3, name: 'People 3'}                 
               ]; 
               $scope.edit = function(id){                   
                   var i = 0;
                   var a = false;
                   while (i < $scope.peoples.length && a === false){
                       if ($scope.peoples[i].id === id){
                           a = true;
                       } else {
                           i++;
                       }
                   }
                   if (i < $scope.peoples.length){
                        window.sessionStorage.setItem('people', JSON.stringify($scope.peoples[i]));
                        window.location.href='edit.html'
                   } else {
                       alert('Item não encontrado');
                   }
               }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="App">
            <ul ng-controller="Controller">
                <li ng-repeat="people in peoples">
                    <a href ng-click="edit(people.id)">{{people.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***edit.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var App = angular.module('App', []);
            App.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http){
               $scope.people = {};
               $scope.init = function(){                   
                   $scope.people = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('people'));
                   window.sessionStorage.removeItem('people');
               }
               $scope.init();
            });           
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Controller">            
            <label for="id">Id:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="people.id" id="id">
            <br>
            <label for="id">Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="people.name"id="name">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Dessa forma, a informação contida na home.html é passada para edit.html.

***Obs:*** esse código pode ser melhorado mediante a sua aplicação web, ou seja, abra o home.html e clique em algum item sendo redirecionado para edit.html e o item clicado vai aparecer nessa outra página. Não fiz questão de colocar um código criticado mas, sim funcional e com isso deve ser adaptado como já disse a sua aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Perfeitamente o que procurava, vamos imaginar, busquei os dados, exibe os mesmos em uma página, quando fosse o momento da edição se eu passa-se o ID desse objeto pela url, e nessa nova página captura-se esse ID para buscar os dados e assim exibi-los para a edição, seria inviável correto? pois fiz duas requisições, uma para exibir todos os dados e a outra para exibir apenas de um determinado. Sua solução foi bem interessante, obrigado!

Comment: Se resolveu o problema marque como resposta :)

Answer (score 1):

Por "outra página," você se refere a um outro site externo ou outra view dentro da própria Single-Page Application servida pelo AngularJS?

Se for dentro do Angular, você pode criar um service para requirir informações de um backend e manter o estado nele. Para isso, há duas maneiras: usando service ou usando factory.

Depois de fazer o service, você apenas terá que injetar no seu controller que irá precisar das informações que você está se referindo.

Escrevi [aqui](https://jsbin.com/xuqenaceha/1/edit?html,output) um exemplo. Espero que ajude a entender mais o Angular.

No exemplo, temos a pagina inicial que leva você à lista de usuários. De lá, você pode ver o perfil de um certo usuário. A view da lista de usuários e a view do perfil têm controllers diferentes, mas compartilham o mesmo service, que eu chamei de UsuariosModel. Então os dados persistem entre as views se você usar um service. :)

Note que eu pus tudo (os codigos e templates) inline para poder rodar tudo de uma vez no JSBIN e aqui no Stack Overflow. Em prática, você teria que separar tudo em arquivos diferentes para melhor estruturar o seu aplicativo web.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exemploApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      .painel-de-usuario {
        background-color: AntiqueWhite;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 12px;
        padding: 12px;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
      }
      .perfil-de-usuario {
        background-color: #ecc7c7;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 3px solid blue;
        border-radius: 9px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ui-view></div>

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular UI Router -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="usuarios.tmpl.html">
      <h1>Lista de usuários</h1>
      <div class="painel-de-usuario" ng-repeat="usuario in ctrl.usuarios">
        <p>
          Id: {{usuario.id}}
        </p>
        <p>
          Nome: {{usuario.nome}}
        </p>
        <p>
          Idade: {{usuario.idade}}
        </p>
        <a href="#/usuarios/{{usuario.id}}">Ver perfil</a>
      </div>

      <h4>Debug:</h4>
      {{ctrl}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="perfil.tmpl.html">
      <h1>Ver Perfil</h1>
      <p>
        Esse é o perfil do usuário com identificação {{ctrl.perfil.id}}
      </p>

      <div class="perfil-de-usuario">
        <p>
          <strong>Nome:</strong> {{ctrl.perfil.nome}}
        </p>
        <p>
          <strong>Idade:</strong> {{ctrl.perfil.idade}}
        </p>
      </div>

      <a ui-sref="usuarios">Voltar pra lista de usuarios</a>

      <h4>Debug:</h4>
      {{ctrl}}
    </script>

    <script>
      angular.module('exemploApp', ['ui.router'])
        .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
          // Pra onde ir se nenhuma rota definida foi pedida
          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

          // Defina todos os states aqui (aka routes (rotas))
          $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
              url: "/home",
              template: `
                <h1>Bem vindos!</h1>
                <a ui-sref="usuarios">Usuarios</a>
              `
            })
            .state('usuarios', {
              url: "/usuarios",
              templateUrl: "usuarios.tmpl.html",
              controller: "UsuariosCtrl",
              controllerAs: "ctrl",
            })
            .state('perfil', {
              url: "/usuarios/:id",
              templateUrl: "perfil.tmpl.html",
              controller: "PerfilCtrl",
              controllerAs: "ctrl",
            })
          ;
        })

        .controller('UsuariosCtrl', ['UsuariosModel', function(UsuariosModel) {
          var ctrl = this;

          function getUsers() {
            // Para carregar os usuarios usando o service
            UsuariosModel.all()
              .then(function(response) {
                ctrl.usuarios = response;

              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Erro carregando usuarios");
                console.log(error);
              });
          }

          // Carrega todos os usuarios
          getUsers();
        }])

        .controller('PerfilCtrl', ['UsuariosModel', '$stateParams', function(UsuariosModel, $stateParams) {
          var ctrl = this;

          // Para carregar o perfil de um usuario especifico
          function getUser(userId) {
            UsuariosModel.get(userId)
              .then(function(response) {
                ctrl.perfil = response;
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Problema ao carregar perfil do usuario " + userId);
                console.log(error);
              });
          }

          // Carrega perfil do usuario
          getUser($stateParams.id);
        }])

        .service('UsuariosModel', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
          var service = this;

          // Dados fake so de exemplo
          // Normalmente, os dados estariam em um banco de dados no backend
          var DATA = [
            { id: 1, nome: "Pedro", idade: 22 },
            { id: 2, nome: "James", idade: 32 },
            { id: 3, nome: "Ana", idade: 19 },
            { id: 4, nome: "Timothy", idade: 45 },
            { id: 5, nome: "Yumiko", idade: 28 },
            { id: 6, nome: "Xiaoyu", idade: 33 },
          ];

          service.all = function() {
            // NOTA: estou usando $q pra retornar uma promessa com os dados
            // que estao na variavel DATA; isso não é necessário se você tiver
            // um backend, em qual caso você só iria precisar do $http
            // (então remova $q das dependências se estiver usando $http)
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            deferred.resolve(DATA);

            return deferred.promise;

            // Normalmente, você usaria isso se tivesse um backend
            // return $http.get(URL_DO_SEU_BACKEND + "usuarios/").then(extract);

            // Onde extract é definido (no começo do service) como
            // function extract(result) {
            //   return result.data;
            // }
          };

          service.get = function(userId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            deferred.resolve(DATA[userId - 1]);

            return deferred.promise;

            // Normalmente, você usaria isso se tivesse um backend
            // return $http.get(URL_DO_SEU_BACKEND + "usuarios/" + userId).then(extract);

            // Onde extract é definido (no começo do service) como
            // function extract(result) {
            //   return result.data;
            // }
          };

        }])
      ;

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```